# Lambda capture-by-value while transfering ownership

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a RAII style class which manages the ownership certain resources. Therefore, copy constructor and assignment operator are explicitly deleted, only move variants exist and they move the resource and invalidate the source (reference). So far it has worked fine, but now I would like to move an object of that kind into a std::function which is processed somewhere else, so that this object becomes the ownership carrier, and eventually release the object. Luckily C++14 allows one to use move assignment while capturing by value so it looked like the way to go. Something like:

```cpp
std::function<void()> act = [temp = move(resCarrier), description]() mutable {
    try {
// hopefully exception-safe
        auto c = make_unique<DataProcessor>(move(temp), description);
        c->doStuff();
    }  catch (...) {}
};
scheduler->RunLater(move(act));
```

But not so easy. It should work, but it doesn't. Getting messy template errors, eventually ending in this (slightly shorted for clarity).

```cpp
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/std_function.h:161:6: error: use of deleted function ‘<WHOLE SIGNATURE OF CURRENT FUNCTION>::<lambda()>&)’
...
note: ‘<WHOLE SIGNATURE OF CURRENT FUNCTION>::<lambda()>&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
   99 |   std::function<void()> act = [temp = move(resCarrier), description]() mutable
      |                                                                    ^
...
error: use of deleted function ‘TResCarrier::TResCarrier(const TResCarrier&)’
```

So it looks like the compiler basically ignores move semantics and insists on using the copy constructor while capturing the variables in the lambda declaration. And so far I was not able to convince it to handle it differently. The "best" idea so far is creating another level of redirection around the carried object so that it can be copied and captured by value (like shared_ptr around the resource). But that would be runtime overhead for no good reason.

Am I overlooking something or is there a hidden nasty restriction of type erasure behind std::function or a limitation of the lambda-to-function mapping?

Comment: Can you show a [mre]?

Comment: Your not [mcve] lacks of the used `DataProcessor::DataProcessor` and `scheduler->RunLater` at least.

Comment: Hardly, the remaining bits of information are in the description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lambda is not a `std::function`.

You are right that c++14 allows moving something into a lambda, and even move said lambda afterwards.

A `std::function` on the other hand requires the callable to be Copy Constructable and Copy Assignable.

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function#:%7E:text=Instances%20of%20std%3A%3Afunction,target%20of%20std%3A%3Afunction%20.)

> Class template std::function is a general-purpose polymorphic function wrapper. Instances of std::function can store, copy, and invoke any CopyConstructible Callable target -- functions, lambda expressions, bind expressions, or other function objects, as well as pointers to member functions and pointers to data members.

> The stored callable object is called the target of std::function. If a std::function contains no target, it is called empty. Invoking the target of an empty std::function results in std::bad_function_call exception being thrown.

> std::function satisfies the requirements of CopyConstructible and CopyAssignable.

Some ideas for a possible solution could be:

- Create your own function wrapper (or use a library) that supports move-only callables.
- Wrap you `std::unique_pre` in a `std::shared_ptr` and capture that.

The first option seems much more robust, but just to show the idea for a quick dirty work-around.

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    auto moveonly = std::make_unique<int>(5);
    auto wrapped = std::make_shared<std::unique_ptr<int>>(std::move(moveonly));

    auto lam = [wrapped]() {
        return *(*wrapped);
    };

    std::function<int()> f = lam;
}
```

Comment: I know that lambda != std::function but I was not sure WRT the implicit conversion rules. Thanks for pointing at the CopyConstructible requirement, that sadly means that the expected flexibility is not possible to implement as intended. As mentioned, I was already pondering on shared_ptr wrapping, but for performance reasons I will probably take another path, i.e. unlocking the carried object and move it around with a bare pointer, double-checking not to create leaks in case of abortion, maybe giving that lambda another "isCanceled" parameter.